# How to get a sum of column of GridView using JavaScript

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, gridview

I'm trying to access to the column named Time of a gridview and calculate Sum of whole column using JavaScript.

I have something like this:

[image]

So in Report total I want to get number 5, since it is only entry right now.

This is a definition of a gridview:

```
<div class="total">

    <asp:GridView ID="ReportGrid" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False" DataSourceID="SqlDS" Height="68px" Width="813px" AllowPaging="True">
        <Columns>
            <asp:BoundField DataField="Date" HeaderText="Date" SortExpression="Date" DataFormatString="{0:MM/dd/yy}" />
            <asp:BoundField DataField="Name" HeaderText="Team Member Name" SortExpression="Name" />
            <asp:BoundField DataField="ProjectName" HeaderText="Projects" SortExpression="ProjectName" />
            <asp:BoundField DataField="Description" HeaderText="Description" SortExpression="Description" />
            <asp:BoundField DataField="Time" HeaderText="Time" SortExpression="Time" />
        </Columns>
    </asp:GridView>
    <br />
    <br />
    <span>Report total: <em>
        <asp:Label runat="server" ID="totalHours" Text="0"></asp:Label></em></span>
</div>
```

Can anyone help me with javaScript code for this problem or share with me some related links, cause all I've found on the internet wasn't similar to this, and I guess this is simple thing to do when you know how to use JS.

NaN value for sum during debugging:

[image]

Comment: why you want to do that using javascript? if you are using ASP.net ? i guess better to use OnRowBound function of GridView

Comment: @RamzanZafar Thanks for answering. Well I'm trying to do my best with learning JS, that's why I want to try it this way... I guess that one more way is to calculate it directly from the database using Sum() function...

Comment: Yes that can be a good option using SUM() function. You can add a css class to your data fields and then use Jquery class selector to sum those

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add a css class to your fields

```
    <asp:BoundField DataField="Time" HeaderText="Time"> 
      <ItemStyle CssClass="yourclass"></ItemStyle> 
     </asp:BoundField>
```

and use the following code

```
 var fields= document.getElementsByClassName('yourclass');
    var sum = 0;
    for (var i = 0; i < fields.length; ++i) {
        var item = fields[i];  
         sum += parseInt(item.innerHTML);
    }
```

and then assign that sum to your total label

```
$("#<%= totalHours.ClientID %>").text(sum);
```

Comment: Should I add css class to all fields or only the time filed that I'm using? @RamzanZafar

Comment: only to time field! @nemo_87

Comment: I guess I'm doing something wrong...
I've added css class to time field <asp:BoundField DataField="Time" HeaderText="Time" SortExpression="Time" ControlStyle-CssClass="test" /> but when I'm using debugger I see that the fields length is 0... @RamzanZafar

Comment: You need to add item style <asp:BoundField DataField="Time" HeaderText="Time">
    <ItemStyle CssClass="yourclass"></ItemStyle>
</asp:BoundField>

Comment: Now it catches the right filed and it counts one member but for sum I get NaN. I've updated a picture during debugging process where you can see this. I've also added a line for writing sum value into a label, but I'm not sure is it right... Sorry for bothering you this much I'm simply bad in JS right now...@RamzanZafar

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/65214/discussion-between-ramzan-zafar-and-nemo-87).

Comment: can you share that code? that is assigning the sum to total label?

Comment: Sure it is just one line, I will send it to you on chat :) @Ramzan Zafar