# Find out total amout in gridview using javascript

Tags: javascript, asp.net, gridview

I want to retrieve checked total amount.  I am using itemtemplate but I am not able to retrieve total amount please help on this.

```
<asp:GridView ID="gvTicket"  runat="server" CssClass="table" AutoGenerateColumns="false" OnRowDataBound="gvTicket_RowDataBound">
  <Columns>
    <asp:TemplateField>
      <ItemTemplate>
        <asp:CheckBox ID="chkSelect" runat="server" />
      </ItemTemplate>
    </asp:TemplateField>
    <asp:BoundField DataField="nCustomerPk" HeaderText="Id" />
    <asp:BoundField DataField="cTicketNo" HeaderText="Ticket No" />
    <asp:BoundField DataField="dBookDate" HeaderText="Book Date" />
    <asp:BoundField DataField="dDepartDate" HeaderText="Dept. Date" />
    <asp:BoundField DataField="bCancel" HeaderText="Cancel" />
    <asp:BoundField DataField="dCancelDate" HeaderText="Cancel Date" />
    <asp:BoundField DataField="nCancelCharges" HeaderText="Cancel Charge" />
    <asp:BoundField  DataField="nSalesRate"  HeaderText="Amount" />
  </Columns>
</asp:GridView>
```

Comment: Please provide the html output and javascript

Comment: Please refer this : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27017507/how-to-get-a-sum-of-column-of-gridview-using-javascript

Answer (score 1):

The GridView will render as html.  Javascript will work on the rendered html. Providing at least part of the rendered html would have made this easier, so below is a best guess to get you going.

You've mentioned 'javascript' but not ruled out jquery, which makes things like this so much easier.

I've broken it down into steps, this could be a lot shorter / cleaner (it's possible in a single line using map() but this way may help you if it's not 100%).

```
var grid = $("#gvTicket");
var rows = $("tbody>tr", grid);
var tot = 0;
rows.each(function() {
     // >td all td cells that are directly under the row
     // asp.net controls have a horrid tendency to add tables all over the place
     // so you need the > to ensure table>tbody>tr>td (excluding any sub tables)
     var checkCell = $(">td", this)[0]);
     // Look for any controls in checkCell that are :checked (ie the tickbox)
     if ($(":checked", checkCell).length) {
         // Get the cell to sum
         // Wouldn't normally use indexes like this as they're too liable to break
         // it might be possible to add an ID or class to the column and reference that
         var valCell = $(">td", this)[8];
         tot += valCell.text();
     }
});
```

[0] is the first column with the textbox
[8] is the column with nSalesRate

Apologies for any errors, this is off the top of my head without reference to your gridview html.